# Black screen with white text all over appears when I close my laptop's screen/lid

Tags: suspend

So I just closed my laptop's lid and it didn't go into sleep mode, instead my laptop was still running while the lid was closed. Later, when I opened it, there was a black screen with white text/codes all over the screen.

I'm running Ubuntu 20.04.

Comment: It crashed. Look in /var/log/syslog for clues as to why. Check around the time that the lid was closed.